# How to locate different elements present under single Div tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Please check the below sample code.

```
<html>
<body
<div id="HOTELS">
<div class="sub-classes">
<label class="control-label go-right">Location</label>
</div>
<div class="sub-classes">
<span class="size13 go-right">
<b>Adults</b>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<body>
<html>`
```

---------Web Driver Code--------------------

```
WebDriver wdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
List<WebElement>elements=wdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='sub-classes'] label"));
for(WebElement located_element : elements)
{
system.out.println(located_element.getText());
}
```

I am trying to locate Label tag and span tag but Didn't find any way except for defining specific location xpath separately for both the elements. I want to do it using cssSelector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this selector...

```
List<WebElement>elements=driver.findElements(
    By.cssSelector(
        "div[class='sub-classes']>label, div[class='sub-classes']>span"
));
```

This will select all labels and spans with `<div class="sub-classes">` as its direct parent. 

If the `label`/`span` are not directly under this `div`, then replace `>` with  (space)

```
List<WebElement>elements=driver.findElements(
    By.cssSelector(
        "div[class='sub-classes'] label, div[class='sub-classes'] span"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below logic.

1. Get all elements with required class
2. Iterate each element to get inner tags / texts.

```html
List<WebElement>elements=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='sub-classes']"));
for(WebElement located_element : elements){
   System.out.println(located_element.getText());
   System.out.println(located_element.findElement(By.xpath("./*")).getTagName());
}
```

output of above code will be

```
Location
label
Adults
span
```